# Which sensor for rotating android phone?

Tags: android, android-sensors

Imagine you are pointing at the TV. You have your phone gripped in your hand. Now, rotate your wrist.

Which sensor would I need to manage to detect such a movement?

Gyroscope?
Orientation?
Accelerometer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sensors `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` and `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` are fine to detect that (as `TYPE_ORIENTATION` is now deprecated).

You will need:

a few matrix:

```
private float[] mValuesMagnet      = new float[3];
private float[] mValuesAccel       = new float[3];
private float[] mValuesOrientation = new float[3];

private float[] mRotationMatrix    = new float[9];
```

a listener to catch the values the sensors send (this will be an argument of `SensorManager.registerListener()` that you will have to call to setup your sensors):

```
private final SensorEventListener mEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // Handle the events for which we registered
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {           
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER: 
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mValuesAccel, 0, 3); 
                break; 

            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD: 
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mValuesMagnet, 0, 3); 
                break; 
    }
};
```

And you'll need to compute the azimuth, pitch, and roll:

```
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null, mValuesAccel, mValuesMagnet);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mValuesOrientation);
```

`mValuesOrientation` is then filled with:

- `mValuesOrientation[0]`: azimuth, rotation around the Z axis.
- `mValuesOrientation[1]`: pitch, rotation around the X axis.
- `mValuesOrientation[2]`: roll, rotation around the Y axis.

Check the [documentation of getOrientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) to know how the axis are defined. You may need to use `SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem()` to redefine these axis.

Comment: When I do this, the pitch never goes to 180°. It starts at 0° (flat, facing the sky), then goes to 90° when the phone is facing me, then goes back to 90° when it faces the floor. Is that an expected behavior? How do I know if the device is staring the sky or the floor then?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to detect, if you want to detect that the phone has been moved in a rotation then accelerometer is probably your best bet.
If you want to detect that the phone is now rotated then Orientation.

Answer (score 0):

The [gyroscope](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion#sensors-motion-gyro) is for detecting rotations if you don't care about your position relative to the Earth.