# How to detect change in orientation of android phone from horizontal position to vertical position?

Tags: java, android, orientation, sensors

I am unable to undertand and find out how to detect the change in orientation of android phone from horizontal to vertical position. Here i am not talking about orientation change between portrait or landscape. Example can be like i have phone in horizontal position lying on a floor and then i lift up to see the screen from front. So actually the phone had a transition from one axis to another.

Can i do it using Rotation Vector sensor?

Comment: This might solve your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846743/which-sensor-for-rotating-android-phone

Answer (score 1):

You will need the Gravity Sensor:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

In the absence of a Gravity Sensor you have to rely on Accelerometer and Gyroscope, I think.

Comment: Yes ! using gravity sensor worked for me. Gravity sensor shows change from 0 to +9 while moving phone from one position to another. Thanks ev1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at my answer to [Android Compass that can Compensate for Tilt and Pitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317599/android-compass-that-can-compensate-for-tilt-and-pitch/16386066#16386066).  In the code that I posted, the variable m_pitch_radians will be zero when the phone is lying on the floor, and PI/2 (i.e. 90 degrees) when it's standing upright.