# How to detect magnetic north / azimuth without Magnetometer

Tags: android, android-sensors, magnetometer, sensormanager

I'm working on an Android device which does not have a Magnetometer but has a Rotation Sensor (Gyro) and Gravity Sensor and GPS. I would like to determine **True North / Azimuth** from these sensors but can't figure out how. Without a Magnetometer, how do I determine the orientation of this device? Clearly somehow it knows where North is given the Maps app works just fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711705/android-device-orientation-without-geomagnetic

Comment: @Ircover Thanks, I've updated my question, I guess it's 'true north' that I'm after, not just the orientation of the device (as that would return 0 for it facing straight up). Essentially I am trying to create a compass with the given constraints

Comment: If the device moves (more than just a few meters), then the GPS can provide you the direction of the movement. Theoretically you could use that to "calibrate" the rotation sensor and then track the device's rotation with it. Of course in practice things get complicated, if the device rotates over several axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

You can the [Rotation Vector Sensor](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate) that seems perfect for your situation.

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
```

The system of coordinates you want is as follows:

- X is defined as the vector product Y x Z. It is tangential to the ground at the device's current location and **points approximately East**.
- Y is tangential to the ground at the device's current location and points **toward the geomagnetic North Pole**.
- Z points toward the sky and is perpendicular to the ground plane.

[image]

---

Android makes a **lot** of sensors available

if you specifically wish to use the gyroscope (`Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE`) you could do it like this (taken from the [Google example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro)):

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
      //...
}
```

but you could try and check if you can use a higher level API that will leverage more than one sensor

You should have a look at this [simple example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-compass-code-example.html) by JavaCodeGeeks where they leverage the default `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` to build an android compass

Just a little more info on the Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION.  [According to Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-orient) you can still use device orientation, but by calling `getOrientation()` instead of acting directly over the sensor.

> Instead of using raw data from the orientation sensor, we recommend
>   that you use the `getRotationMatrix()` method in conjunction with the
>   `getOrientation()` method to compute orientation values, as shown in the
>   following code sample. As part of this process, you can use the
>   `remapCoordinateSystem()` method to translate the orientation values to
>   your application's frame of reference.

The bad news is that both `getOrientation()` and the old `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` rely at least partially on the magnetometer

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for this, I know how to use the gyro sensor - I just don't know how to determine 'true north' from its readings as I need to first get an idea of where North is. TYPE_ORIENTATION sadly is deprecated and so not available for use :(

Comment: I will have another look then ;)

Comment: thank you, I'll mark that as the correct answer, although the hardware I'm on doesn't give me any readings for TYPE_ROTATION :( But that sounds like the only other choice I may have.

Comment: Thanks ;)
Have you noticed that it is actually TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR and not TYPE_ROTATION? (just making sure)

Comment: Yup thanks for double checking, that's what I meant :) It's a car's dashboard I'm working with and apparently it's not willing to play ball

Comment: But `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` uses the magnetometer though?